# add php sodium extension in google cloud build

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, php-extension

hi im new to google cloud platform this is my first project,i want to deploy an laravel app to google cloud build and im using several php-extension, i cant install sodium ext, here is my app.yml, cloudbuild.yml, and composer.json.
app.yml

```
runtime: php
env: flex
runtime_config:
    document_root: web
skip_files: 
    - .env

automatic_scaling:
    min_num_instances: 1
    max_num_instances: 1

resources:
    cpu: 2
    memory_gb: 4
    disk_size_gb: 100

env_variables:
    # Put production environment variables here.
    APP_DEBUG: true
    APP_ENV: production
    APP_KEY: base64:vlhXQJ75jQOpBJ7NtPLFAc3oaaYDD7YQD2YSiF1A34I=
    APP_NAME: "GCP App - CODE"

    LOG_LEVEL: debug
```

cloudbuild.yml

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
        - '-c'
        - |
          gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 3600 \
          && gcloud app deploy -q --promote -v=$BUILD_ID \
          --project=$PROJECT_ID

timeout: '3600s'
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "ext-grpc": "*",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-sodium": "*",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "google/cloud-firestore": "^1.25",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "itsgoingd/clockwork": "^5.1",
        "kreait/laravel-firebase": "^4.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^2.62",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables": "^1.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache",
            "php artisan cache:clear"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "platform-check": false,
        "platform": {
            "php": "^7.3|^8.0"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

and this is the error

```
Step #2: Using PHP version: 7.3
Step #2: Install PHP extensions...
Step #2: Failed to install all requested extensions:
Step #2: - sodium * is not available on your system.
Step #2: error building image: error building stage: waiting for process to exit: exit status 1
Finished Step #2
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor@sha256:f87c11770a4d3ed33436508d206c584812cd656e6ed08eda1cff5c1ee44f5870" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Iam tring to deploy my laravel with google cloud build

Answer (score 0):

In the `config` section, you should add a new property to the `platform` settings, which refers to sodium, something like

```
"config": {
    ...
    "platform": {
        "php": "8.1",
        "ext-sodium": "8.1"
    }
}
```